# Protocol based IBOutlets in swift, trouble hooking up

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, uistoryboard, iboutlet

I have a data source and a delegate protocol, which I use to extend UIViewController.

In a simple class I add a data source and delegate as outlets

```
@objc protocol TestDataSource {
}

@objc protocol TestDelegate {
}

extension UIViewController: TestDataSource, TestDelegate {
}

class OutletTest: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet var dataSource: TestDataSource?
    @IBOutlet var delegate: TestDelegate?
}
```

I've made the extension with UIViewController because I want to add the object to my view controller dock and hook up the outlets to the view controller, as below

[image]

I can see the outlets are recognised by IB, but now I hit the problem. When I try to hook up my view controller as both my data source and delegate, I am only given the option of hooking up the data source

[image]

Stranger still, if I reverse the order of my data source and delegate in the UIViewController extension, I only get the delegate as an option

```
extension UIViewController: TestDelegate, TestDataSource {
}
```

[image]

**Workaround**
I have a workaround involving a third protocol which combines the first two

```
@objc protocol TestDataSource {
}

@objc protocol TestDelegate {
}

@objc protocol CombinedProtocol: TestDelegate, TestDataSource  {
}

extension UIViewController: CombinedProtocol {
}

class OutletTest: NSObject {
    @IBOutlet var dataSource: CombinedProtocol?
    @IBOutlet var delegate: CombinedProtocol?
}
```

Doing this gives me the option to hook up both of the outlets, but it seems hacky and just a little dangerous.

[image]

Does this seem like a bug in Xcode/IB, or is there a reason for this?

Comment: Try to make single `extantion` for each `protocol`

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried that as well. If I write two extensions for UIViewController I only see the first one in the list, same as above.